# jQuery HTML editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, editor

For my current project i am creating a html editor.

### **How its needs to work**

***Elements Inside***

1. Text Area - To type the HTML as text
2. Iframe - To show the typed HTML as real [rendering the string HTML to UI]
3. Some Buttons

***Working Logic***

A registered user typing something inside the text area :

ex :

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">This is a div</div>
```

after that user clicks on a button [Converting to UI],so that we need to change the iframe content to the new value [value of text area]

after converting the iframe elements html will be

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .mydiv{

  }
</style>
 </head>
<body>

<div class="mydiv" style="color:red">This is a div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is another button that which give back the iframe HTML to text area ,

All these works good [No big problems now except the firebug issue],But i need to integrate a better UI to customize the iframe content - >

ex : User clicks on a `DIV` on iframe ,so that time a pop up will arise to change the color and font of that div [it will be some color picker for choosing color and drop down for to choose font][i need to implement some more like this]. hope that it will not be a big pain.

So after that i need to get the modified value.

Ex: i changed the color of a div ,

so the returned value will be something like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="mydiv" style="color:gray;">Hello World !</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### **TO DO**

1. Please note the style attribute [above ] ,its in inline style ,i
   need to convert it into the class scope if the element have a class
   defined
   so i need to add/update the css class "mydiv" with new style's .
2. Assume that we are changing something on the `body` element of iframe ,`body` is a common element so i need to add/update the `BODY` scope in the css style block

   ex:

   BODY{
   color:gray;
   }

   I hope that you guys got my idea,i need to implement something like this on my current project.

Is there anything slimier this ? [so that no need to worry ,i can use that]
or 
How can i achieve this ? especially the grouping of css class.

I hopes that i need to use some kind of regular expressions ,but i am very weak on this.

Please help me to complete.

**What i tried is here** : http://jsfiddle.net/5PKXq/3/

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to create another editor? There are plenty of it, mostly known tinyMCE ?

Comment: i know about this ,but i will use tinymic only to replace that text area

Comment: what i need to do is grouping the class.

Comment: You are still a long way from home. Definitely when you lack regex skills. I opened up your fiddle and played around with it a bit, but so many things need to be done, so many exceptions to be covered. You'll have to ask some more specific questions rather than: "please help me to complete". There are perfectly good alternatives such as http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/ and http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: also take a look at these: http://icodesnippet.com/search?q=regex%20css%20attributes They are various CSS selecting snippets, quite sure some of them will help you reach your targets.

Comment: @Gert Van de Ven actually what i showed her is just a example only,i need to work more ,currently i am using Codemirror,i looked almost all plugins currently have,but none of them satisfying me,i will look thaat css snippets ,thanks alot for that

Answer (score 0):

Much as I think you're really reinventing the wheel here, I don't see what's keeping you from getting the contents of the `textarea`, and then just appending it directly to, I don't know, a container `div` (it doesn't even have to be an `iframe`, which I personally think is a bad way to go).

```
var $textarea = $('textarea'),
    $container = $('div#container'),
    $refresh = $('button#refresh'),  // or something
    ;

$refresh.on('click', function () {
    $container.empty()
              .html($textarea.val())
              ;
    // or something
});
```

Do note that that's untested code.